# Oracle SQL- Apply a "Unique ID" Column, Based on Other Column Values

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that pulls multiple properties and their daily details in and I'm needing a way to identify all the failures uniquely within each property. This is an edit to the post, but wanted to note that the dates do come in a unique timestamp form, so there shouldn't be any overlapping. I also added a Row_Number column partitioned by Property and Date/Timestamp, per recommendation.

[Example Table](https://imgur.com/a/DBpjoBR)

Failures are one-line rows that are defined by the "Failure Flag" column as a value= 'Y', along with a Failure Type. The failure isn't completely over until the activity log ends the "Trouble Flag" column, marked by value= 'Y'. Trouble Type will also indicate what issues are happening. The goal is to create a "Failure ID" column that will apply a group ID to the Failure and it's associated Trouble Flagged rows.

I've tried to do a basic kind of count approach, but this didn't work the way I was hoping... thinking this may be more of a DenseRank opportunity here?

```
case
  when Failure_flag= 'Y' and Trouble_Type is not null then count(Trouble_Type) over (partition by Prprty order by Date)
  else null
  end as Failure_count
```

**Important things to note:** There are multiple Failure Types and Trouble Types and there can be multiple failures of the same Failure Types and Trouble Types within the same day (or on a later date) or property!

Hopefully this situation makes sense... please let me know if further clarification is needed! Appreciate any advice or help offered!

Comment: Assuming this came from a flat file or some non-relational output that is in correct order, you would need to load it into Oracle along with the row number (within the file). You then would have something you could use to order your analytical function along with the failure flag to group rows appropriately. But if you load this data as shown in your picture without any line number or any other kind of sequential value, there is no way to group the proper rows together. In Oracle, data has no inherent order at rest in a table. So make sure any conceptual order is described by an actual column.

Comment: Okay that's not a problem. I can go ahead and give them all a row_number, based on the ascending date... if that's what you mean. If I added this row_number by Date ASC, what would my logic function look like? I'm stumped.

Comment: Your date is not sequential - it would need to have a different value for every row. Otherwise you can't support multiple failures on the same day nor can you deal with overlapping failures. You'll need to add the row number from your source, not derive it within Oracle.

Comment: I should have clarified better... the date is in timestamp form, so each line should be unique and I've applied the row_number and it works perfectly for each record. No time stamp from the data will be overlapped.

Comment: And failures cannot overlap in time? Only one failure at any given moment?

Comment: Correct, only one failure at a given moment.

Comment: Provided an answer. You'll need to adapt to your actual data, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date col (which cannot actually be named "date" as that's a reserved keyword) is a date with time in it or a timestamp and is unique, always increasing in the order of the line depicted in your image, and there is no overlapping failures, then you can use that to identify each failure using two sets of analytical functions, one of which uses the `IGNORE NULLS` option in combination with `DECODE` (to mark unwanted rows with a `NULL`) to find that failure flag row and return its timestamp value, which is then later used to do the ranking. Something like this demonstrates the technique:

```
/* testdata */ WITH data AS (SELECT SYSDATE mydate, NULL failure_flag FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT SYSDATE + 0.05 mydate, NULL failure_flag FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT SYSDATE + 0.1 mydate, 'Y' failure_flag FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT SYSDATE + 0.3 mydate, NULL failure_flag FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT SYSDATE + 0.4 mydate, 'Y' failure_flag FROM dual)
SELECT x.*,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY flag_timestamp) failure_id
  FROM (SELECT x.*, 
               FIRST_VALUE(DECODE(failure_flag,'Y',mydate) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY mydate ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) flag_timestamp       
          FROM data x) x
 ORDER BY mydate
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm working with this now and will let you know how it goes. I think it's pretty darn close to what I need. Like you mentioned, gotta tweak it to work with my data. I'm seeing one small issue that I think I can work out with a case statement, but I need it to only provide a Failure ID when Failure_Flag is 'Y' and Trouble_Time_Flag is 'Y' or while all rows after have a 'Y' value for the Trouble_Time_Flag.